# How can I extract the following links from html source code in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

Here is my some html source code :

```html
<div class="s">
   <div class="th N3nEGc" style="height:48px;width:61px">
<a href="/imgres?imgurl=https://linuxhint.com/wpcontent/uploads/2018/12/11.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=https://linuxhint.com/setup_screensaver_manjaro_linux/&amp;h=912&amp;w=1140&amp;tbnid=10DzCgmImE0jM&amp;tbnh=201&amp;tbnw=251&amp;usg=K_YJsquLr4rorhW2ks8UdceQ8uKjg=&amp;docid=0vImrzSjsr5zQM"
         data-ved="2ahUKEwj3062g3pDjAhWZQN4KHS-_BL8Q8g0wC3oECAUQBQ"
         ping="/urlsa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=/imgres%3Fimgurl%3Dhttps://linuxhint.com/wpcontent/uploads/2018/12/11.jpg%26imgrefurl%3Dhttps://linuxhint.com/setup_screensaver_manjaro_linux/%26h%3D912%26w%3D1140%26tbnid%3D10DzCgmImE0jM%26tbnh%3D201%26tbnw%3D251%26usg%3DK_YJsquLr4rorhW2ks8UdceQ8uKjg%3D%26docid%3D0vImrzSjsr5zQM&amp;ved=2ahUKEwj3062g3pDjAhWZQN4KHS-_BL8Q8g0wC3oECAUQBQ">
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want to extract is the link:
`<a href="/imgres?imgurl=https://linuxhint.com/wpcontent/uploads/2018/12/11.jpg&amp;`

so the output will be in that way,

```
https://linuxhint.com/wpcontent/uploads/2018/12/11.jpg
```

What I tried by using python is :

```
 sourceCode = opener.open(googlePath).read().decode('utf-8')
 links = re.findall('href="/imgres?imgurl=(.*?)jpg&amp;imgrefurl="',sourceCode)
 for i in links:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Better way than parse query string through `regex` is using `parse_qs` function (safer, you get exactly what you want without `regex` fiddling) ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=parse_qs#urllib.parse.parse_qs)):

```
data = '''<div class="s"><div class="th N3nEGc" style="height:48px;width:61px"><a href="/imgres?imgurl=https://linuxhint.com/wpcontent/uploads/2018/12/11.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=https://linuxhint.com/setup_screensaver_manjaro_linux/&amp;h=912&amp;w=1140&amp;tbnid=10DzCgmImE0jM&amp;tbnh=201&amp;tbnw=251&amp;usg=K_YJsquLr4rorhW2ks8UdceQ8uKjg=&amp;docid=0vImrzSjsr5zQM" data-ved="2ahUKEwj3062g3pDjAhWZQN4KHS-_BL8Q8g0wC3oECAUQBQ" ping="/urlsa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=/imgres%3Fimgurl%3Dhttps://linuxhint.com/wpcontent/uploads/2018/12/11.jpg%26imgrefurl%3Dhttps://linuxhint.com/setup_screensaver_manjaro_linux/%26h%3D912%26w%3D1140%26tbnid%3D10DzCgmImE0jM%26tbnh%3D201%26tbnw%3D251%26usg%3DK_YJsquLr4rorhW2ks8UdceQ8uKjg%3D%26docid%3D0vImrzSjsr5zQM&amp;ved=2ahUKEwj3062g3pDjAhWZQN4KHS-_BL8Q8g0wC3oECAUQBQ">'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

d = urlparse(soup.select_one('a[href*="imgurl"]')['href'])
q = parse_qs(d.query)

print(q['imgurl'])
```

Prints:

```
['https://linuxhint.com/wpcontent/uploads/2018/12/11.jpg']
```

Comment: Hi, your code is working fine with the above piece of code, but when I try to process it with whole the source code then its showing me the following error.     print(q['imgurl'])
KeyError: 'imgurl'

Comment: @sodmzs You need to select the right element from the soup. I updated my code.

Comment: Thanks its working now but it's just showing me only one link when there are multiple links available in the source code within the same tags like the piece of source code in my question.

Comment: @sodmzs you need then use select() method, not select_one() and use for-loop to go through all the links selected by this method.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is your regex, then I think you can try this one:

```
link = re.search('^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*[^.\\,:;]', sourceCode)
link = link.group()
print (link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should add an escape character for '?', try out this :

```
links = re.findall('href="/imgres\?imgurl=(.*?)jpg&amp;imgrefurl="',sourceCode)
for i in links:
    print(i)
```